# Riddle cannot detect Sphinx on your machine, and so can't determine whichversion of Sphinx you are planning on using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, osx-lion, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am getting this error in my console. I just formatted my whole machine. I never this kind of error. Anybody whole can guide me what this riddle is.

```
Riddle cannot detect Sphinx on your machine, and so can't determine which version of Sphinx you are planning on using. Please use one of the following lines after "require 'riddle'" to avoid this warning.

 require 'riddle/0.9.8'
 # or
 require 'riddle/0.9.9'
 # or
 require 'riddle/1.10'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Riddle](https://github.com/freelancing-god/riddle) is a Ruby client for Sphinx, which is use in [Thinking Sphinx](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/) to integrate Sphinx with Rails.

How are you accessing Sphinx from Rails? It looks like the config needs to be set to point at the installation of Sphinx, so that the correct version of Riddle can be loaded. If you are using Thinking Sphinx, try setting the `bin_path` in the *config/sphinx.yml*.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to update the [Thinking Sphinx plugin](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/tags) or gem to the latest version, for Rails 2.3.x this is currently version 1.4.11, for Rails 3.x it is version 2.0.13.